# Issue using setTimeout to animate in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, settimeout

I'm trying to animate vertical rows of circles that are recurring, one row at a time. Each row of circles starts at the bottom of the browser and goes to the top. But I'm having trouble using setTimeout to keep it recurring with only one new line of circles at a time. My current code has recurring lines of circles, but it adds an extra line of circles each time and speeds up the animation each time as well. How can I avoid the speeding up and adding extra rows of circles?

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thoughtsailor/6o941d95/)

```
var newLine = function(){
        var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            posY = canvas.height;

        setInterval(function() {
            posY -= 40;

            c.fillStyle = "rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.05)";
            c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(posX, posY, Math.random() * 20, 0, twoPi, false);
            c.fill();

        }, 30);
        setTimeout(newLine, 2000);
    };  
    newLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call `newLine()` it creates a new interval timer. So after calling the function several times you have several interval timers all running at once.

The fix is simply to clear the interval timer before starting a new one:

```
    var timer;

    var newLine = function(){
        clearInterval( timer );
        var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            posY = canvas.height;

        timer = setInterval(function() {
            posY -= 40;

            c.fillStyle = "rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.05)";
            c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(posX, posY, Math.random() * 20, 0, twoPi, false);
            c.fill();

        }, 30);
        setTimeout(newLine, 2000);
    };  
    newLine();
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o941d95/13/)

About your question in the comments... One problem you're running to is a very subtle JavaScript trap. I didn't notice it either until doing some debugging.

Take a close look at these lines:

```
        var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            posY = canvas.height;
```

Now ask yourself these questions: Is `posX` a local variable? Is `posY` a local variable? Are you sure they're both local variables?

If you saw some results in your tests where two or or more of the line animations move up in lockstep, this will explain why.

The other part of your question is easy. Disregard my previous advice about moving the `timer` variable outside the `newLine()` function so you can cancel it! Instead, make `timer` a *local* variable inside `newLine()`, and make each instance of `newLine()` cancel its own timer when done.

Once you do that, the rest of your code works fine:

```
    var newLine = function(){
        var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        var posY = canvas.height;

        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            posY -= 10;
            if( posY <= 0 ) {
                clearInterval( timer );
                return;
            }

            c.fillStyle = "rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.05)";
            c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            c.fillStyle = "white";
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(posX, posY, Math.random() * 5, 0, twoPi, false);
            c.fill();

        }, 30);

        setTimeout( newLine, Math.random() * 2000 );
    };

    newLine();
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o941d95/28/)

Comment: thank you. Is there a best practice to have multiple rows like this animating on the screen at once? In my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thoughtsailor/6o941d95/27/) you can see I have the rows animating one after another correctly, now at random intervals between 0 and 2 seconds. except when their timing is too close together, the new row interrupts the previous row. I'd like to have all the rows reach the top of the browser instead of being stopped mid-screen when a new row starts animating. any help with this would be fantastic.

Comment: Yeah, I gave you some bum advice about canceling the timer. The real trick is to make each instance of `newLine()` responsible for canceling its own timer - see above for update. And BTW I meant to ask you: how is the fading-out effect being done, where each of your circles fades out over time? I don't see anything in the code doing that fading! What did I miss? :-)

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much! this is super helpful. I achieved the fading effect by originally giving window.onload a fillstyle of #232323 (not included above) and then in my function above I'm updating the fillstyle's alpha channel when the function is called with this bit of code `c.fillStyle = "rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.05)"`. 0.05 giving it a 5% transparency.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thanks! I was looking for code that faded out the circles or *changed* some opacity level over time. But instead you're simply drawing a nearly-transparent solid rectangle every time, and that naturally fades out everything that's already on the canvas. Very nice trick, I will definitely use this sometime.

Comment: BTW, minor thing I just noticed... `23` doesn't mean the same thing in the two places the code uses it. `#232323` is 23 hex (35 decimal), but `rgba(23,23,23,0.05)` is 23 decimal. Probably doesn't matter at all in this particular context, but something to watch out for in general with these CSS color values.

Comment: thanks for the tip, again :) I'm new to canvas so this is great.

Comment: Mind if I ask you another question? In my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thoughtsailor/3e32L57a/) you can see that each row of circles reaches the top of the browser, but then waits there until an new row begins before fully fading away. Is there a way to avoid the pause when it reaches the top? I'd like to have it keep fading normally whether or not a new row enters the screen. Thanks a million in advance.